Error when entering data via Telegram bot for the second time
Error when creating a telegram bot, when entering the Name/Email/Phone, I ask him to do this again, then he gives me the following error message:
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4 /spreadsheets/1saG-
dfVZEUmu_dLoOjm85XEc0xyMIQMLUWslXTVjrQc/values/DadosTelegram%21A5%3AD5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Requested writing within range [DadosTelegram!A5:D5], but tried writing to column [E]". Details: "Requested writing within range [DadosTelegram!A5:D5], but tried writing to column [E]">

I tried to insert the data for the second time when running the telegram bot through python, it inserted the first data, however on the second attempt to insert the data, it gave an error.
import os.path
import datetime
import telebot
import requests
import io
from PIL import Image

from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery, InputMediaPhoto
from functools import partial
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

CHAVE_API = "secret"

bot = telebot.TeleBot("secret")

#mensagem de continuidade do bot
message_continius = "Você está no controle! Se quiser experimentar outras opções ou precisar de mais informações, estou à disposição:"

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'secret'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'DadosTelegram!A1:D10'



def main():
    global user_data
    user_data = {}
    bot.polling()

def save_to_google_sheets(user_data):
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secret.json', SCOPES
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        # Determine the next empty row in the first column
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
            range="DadosTelegram!A:A"  # Check the entire column A
        ).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])
        next_empty_row = len(values) + 1

        range_name = f"DadosTelegram!A{next_empty_row}:D{next_empty_row}" # Assume you have 4 columns of data
        user_data_values = user_data + [datetime.date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')]
        values_update = [
            user_data_values,
        ]

        # Update the range name based on the next empty row
        range_name = f"DadosTelegram!A{next_empty_row}:D{next_empty_row}"

        result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
            range=range_name,
            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
            body={'values': values_update}
        ).execute()

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def send_welcome(message):
    user_data[message.chat.id] = []
    response = requests.get("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1046247245303001109/1228049740508168284/ConsisteLogo.png?ex=662aa172&is=66182c72&hm=bc9562674b28a5a3255d6290507b60cda73976a9d478f4d194b73cb86914ed50&=&format=webp&quality=lossless")
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    img.save("temp.webp", "webp")
    with open("temp.webp", "rb") as f:
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, f)
    os.remove("temp.webp")
    send_keyboard(message, "Olá, Seja bem vindo a Consiste! Escolha uma opção para continuar:")

def send_keyboard(message, message_text):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = InlineKeyboardButton("Saber Mais Sobre a Consiste", callback_data="opcao1")
    button2 = InlineKeyboardButton("Quero Entrar em Contato com a Consiste", callback_data="opcao2")
    button3 = InlineKeyboardButton("Quero que a Consiste entre em contato comigo", callback_data="opcao3")
    button4 = InlineKeyboardButton("Finalizar Atendimento", callback_data="finalizar")
    keyboard.row(button1)
    keyboard.row(button2)
    keyboard.row(button3)
    keyboard.row(button4)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "opcao1":
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id,"https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQG7G7Gl7htZbQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1517610064166?e=1718236800&v=beta&t=DFmyD5O8UI4KusfYf9jxx-ZfjZ51rnFQ3tnQaqZrvdg")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Esté é Marcos Vinicius Fonseca, nosso Presidente")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"""CONSISTE: Servindo ao Sucesso
    
    Na CONSISTE, nossa missão é clara: impulsionar o sucesso dos nossos clientes. Combinamos paixão por tecnologia e comprometimento com resultados para oferecer soluções inovadoras.
    
    Nossa equipe, composta por profissionais íntegros e criativos, trabalha em um ambiente de confiança e colaboração, onde o cliente é prioridade absoluta.
    
    O XTR, nossa solução, é flexível e adaptável a diversas áreas. Desde a coleta de dados até o relacionamento com clientes, promove uma gestão eficiente e focada em resultados tangíveis.
    
    Venha conhecer a CONSISTE e descubra como podemos ajudar a impulsionar o seu sucesso empresarial, na CONSISTE, servir é nossa paixão e seu sucesso, nossa prioridade. para saber mais acesse: https://www.consiste.com.br/portal.nsf/index.xsp""")
        send_keyboard(call.message, message_continius)
    elif call.data == "opcao2":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, """
                            Você pode entrar em contato com a Consiste das seguintes formas: 
            Fone: (71) 2102-6969
            E-mail: contato@consiste.com.br
Para saber mais você também pode entrar em nosso Site: https://www.consiste.com.br/portal.nsf/index.xsp""")
        send_keyboard(call.message, message_continius)
#Pedindo Nome
    elif call.data == "opcao3":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Você Escolheu: Quero que a Consiste entre em contato comigo")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Por favor, digite seu Nome:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, partial(get_email, user_id=call.message.chat.id))
#Finalizando Conversa
    elif call.data == "finalizar":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Atendimento finalizado, a Consiste agradeçe!")
        bot.clear_step_handler(call.message)
        
def get_email(message, user_id):
    user_data[user_id].append(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Por favor, nos informe seu E-mail:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, partial(get_telefone, user_id=user_id))

def get_telefone(message, user_id):
    user_data[user_id].append(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Por favor, nos informe seu Telefone:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, partial(get_phone, user_id=user_id))

def get_phone(message, user_id):
    phone = message.text
    if len(phone) < 12 and not phone.startswith('+'):
        phone = "+55" + phone
    user_data[user_id].append(phone)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Obrigado pela colaboração, entraremos em contato em breve!")
    send_keyboard(message, message_continius)
    save_to_google_sheets(user_data[user_id])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


From your showing error message of Requested writing within range [DadosTelegram!A5:D5], but tried writing to column [E], I guessed that in this case, the length of the values of values_update might be 5. In your script, from range_name = f"DadosTelegram!A{next_empty_row}:D{next_empty_row}", columns "A" to "D" are used. In that case, when the length of the values is more than 5, such an error occurs. If you want to put both values without the error, how about the following modification?
From:
range_name = f"DadosTelegram!A{next_empty_row}:D{next_empty_row}"

To:
range_name = f"DadosTelegram!A{next_empty_row}"


By this modification, the values are put into the cells using the 1st cell range of "A".
For example, when values_update is ["a", "b", "c", "d"], those values are put into columns "A" to "D". And, when values_update is ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], those values are put into columns "A" to "E".


Show, sucess, very good

@ProgTest Beta About Show, sucess, very good, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
